# facing prob in relaunching the app after restarting the android device

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, localhost

I am using json to connect my application to local server. In my application user can log in and a logged in user can see some review coming from different website like google+, yahoo which is stored in the database of local server. Everything is going fine but only prob is after restarting my android device when i am trying to launch my application again it is showing me a message 'unfortunately, your application has stopped' and my application is getting closed.

this is my logcat error:

```
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at com.example.androidhive.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:127)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-18 15:06:39.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     ... 11 more
```

My dashboardActivity class is :

public class DashboardActivity extends ListActivity {

```
ListView lv;
ListAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
UserFunctions userFunctions;
Button btnLogout;
Spinner clientsSpinner;
Spinner sitesSpinner;   
Button txFB;
Button txTW;
TextView title;

static String dealer = "dealer_rater";
static String google = "google_places";
static String twitter = "Twitter";
static String facebook = "Facebook";
static int incr;
static int no;
static int review_length;
static int length = 90;
int review_profile_id;
JSONArray review;
JSONArray mentions;
JSONArray profile;


int x = 0;
ArrayAdapter<String> heightUnitAdapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check login status in database
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    if (userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())) {
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        clientsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTitle1);
        sitesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTitle2);
        txFB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFB);
        txTW = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTW);
        profile = LoginActivity.profiles;

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);            



        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "ArchivoNarrow-Regular.ttf");       
        btnLogout.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        title.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        String[] heightunit = new String[10];               
        heightunit[0] = "All Reviews";
        heightunit[1] = "Dealer Rate";
        heightunit[2] = "Google+ Local";

        heightUnitAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, heightunit);
        sitesSpinner.setAdapter(heightUnitAdapter);


        ArrayAdapter<String> clientadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        for (int i = -1; i < profile.length()+1; i++) {
            try {
                x++;

                if(i==-1){
                //  array_spinner[i+1] = "All Profiles";
                    clientadapter.add("All Profiles");
                }else { 
                    JSONObject c = profile.getJSONObject(i);
                String client_name = c
                        .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEWS_PRIOFILE_NAME);
                clientadapter.add(client_name);
            //  array_spinner[i+1] = client_name;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        final String[] str = new String[] {
                LoginActivity.TAG_REDIRECT,
                LoginActivity.TAG_URL,
                LoginActivity.TAG_AUTHOR,
                LoginActivity.TAG_RATING,
                LoginActivity.TAG_DATE,
                LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEW };
        final int[] place = new int[] {R.id.link, R.id.urlImage,R.id.author, R.id.rating, 
                R.id.date, R.id.review, };

        // clientadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        clientsSpinner.setAdapter(clientadapter);
        clientsSpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View view, int i, long arg3) {
                        int color = getResources().getColor(R.drawable.white);
                        ((TextView) arg0.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(color);
                        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                                "ArchivoNarrow-Regular.ttf");       
                        ((TextView) arg0.getChildAt(0)).setTypeface(myTypeface);
                        sitesSpinner.setSelection(0);                           

                            String selectedClientName = (String) clientsSpinner
                                        .getSelectedItem();
                                for (int k = 0; k < profile.length(); k++) {
                                    // Storing each json item in variable
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject c = profile.getJSONObject(k);
                                        String client_name = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEWS_PRIOFILE_NAME);
                                        if (selectedClientName.equals(client_name)) {
                                            review_profile_id = Integer.parseInt(c
                                                    .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEWS_PRIOFILE_ID));
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            review = LoginActivity.reviews;
                            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                            // RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)
                            // findViewById(R.id.rating);
                            for (int j = 0; j < review.length(); j++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject c = review.getJSONObject(j);                                     
                                    {
                                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                        int review_profile_id2 = Integer.parseInt(c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEWS_PRIOFILE_ID));
                                        if (review_profile_id == review_profile_id2) {
                                        String url = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_URL);
                                        String author = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_AUTHOR);
                                        String author1 =  Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
                                        String review1 = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEW);
                                        String review =  Html.fromHtml(review1).toString();
                                        String date = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_DATE);
                                        String rating = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_RATING);                                           
                                        String link_raw  = c.getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REDIRECT);
                                        String link =  Html.fromHtml(link_raw).toString();
                                        if (!review.equals("null")) {
                                            if (url.equals(dealer)) {
                                                map.put("review", review);
                                                map.put("author", author);
                                                map.put("date", date);
                                                map.put("rating", rating);
                                                map.put("service", link);
                                                map.put("url", Integer.toString(dealer_image));

                                                listItems.add(map);

                                            } else if (url.equals(google)) {
                                                map.put("review", review);
                                                map.put("author", author);
                                                map.put("date", date);
                                                map.put("rating", rating);
                                                map.put("service", link);
                                                map.put("url", Integer.toString(google_image));

                                                listItems.add(map);

                                            } 

                                        }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }                           

                            // Getting adapter
                            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DashboardActivity.this,
                                    listItems, R.layout.list_item, str, place);
                            ((SimpleAdapter) adapter)
                                    .setViewBinder(new MyBinder());
                            setListAdapter(adapter);


                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    }
                });

            sitesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int l,
                        long arg3) {
                    if (clientsSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
                    int color = getResources().getColor(R.drawable.white);
                    ((TextView) arg0.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(color);
                    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                            "ArchivoNarrow-Regular.ttf");       
                    ((TextView) arg0.getChildAt(0)).setTypeface(myTypeface);
                    int a = sitesSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    switch (a) {
                    case (0):

                                review = LoginActivity.reviews;                                             
                                for (int i = 0; i < review.length(); i++) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject c = review
                                                .getJSONObject(i);
                                        {
                                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                            String url = c
                                                    .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_URL);
                                            String author = c
                                                    .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_AUTHOR);
                                            String author1 =  Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
                                            String date = c
                                                    .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_DATE);
                                            String review1 = c
                                                    .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEW);
                                            String review =  Html.fromHtml(review1).toString();
                                            String rating = c
                                                    .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_RATING);
                                            String link_raw  = c.getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REDIRECT);
                                            String link =  Html.fromHtml(link_raw).toString();

                                            if (!review
                                                    .equals("null")) {
                                                if (url.equals(dealer)) {
                                                    map.put("review",
                                                            review);
                                                    map.put("author", author);
                                                    map.put("date",
                                                            date);
                                                    map.put("rating",
                                                            rating);
                                                    map.put("service", link);
                                                    map.put("url", Integer.toString(dealer_image));

                                                    listItems
                                                            .add(map);
                                                } else if (url
                                                        .equals(google)) {
                                                    map.put("review",
                                                            review);
                                                    map.put("author", author);
                                                    map.put("date",
                                                            date);
                                                    map.put("rating",
                                                            rating);
                                                    map.put("service", link);
                                                    map.put("url", Integer.toString(google_image));

                                                    listItems
                                                            .add(map);
                                                } 
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }                                                               

                                // Getting adapter
                                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                        DashboardActivity.this,
                                        listItems,
                                        R.layout.list_item, str,
                                        place);
                                ((SimpleAdapter) adapter)
                                        .setViewBinder(new MyBinder());
                                setListAdapter(adapter);
                                break;
                    case (1):
                        review = LoginActivity.reviews;                                 
                    for (int i = 0; i < review.length(); i++) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject c = review
                                    .getJSONObject(i);
                            String url = c
                                    .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_URL);
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                             {
                                if (url.equals(dealer)) {
                                    String review1 = c
                                            .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEW);
                                    String review =  Html.fromHtml(review1).toString();
                                    String author = c
                                            .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_AUTHOR);
                                    String date = c
                                            .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_DATE);
                                    String rating = c
                                            .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_RATING);
                                    String link_raw  = c.getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REDIRECT);
                                    String link =  Html.fromHtml(link_raw).toString();

                                    if (!review
                                            .equals("null")) {
                                        map.put("review",
                                                review);
                                        map.put("author", author);
                                        map.put("date",
                                                date);
                                        map.put("rating",
                                                rating);
                                        map.put("service", link);
                                        map.put("url", Integer.toString(dealer_image));


                                        listItems
                                                .add(map);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                   
                    // Getting adapter
                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            DashboardActivity.this,
                            listItems,
                            R.layout.list_item, str,
                            place);
                    ((SimpleAdapter) adapter)
                            .setViewBinder(new MyBinder());
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                    break;

                    }
                    }
                    else{
                        int color = getResources().getColor(R.drawable.white);
                        ((TextView) arg0.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(color);
                        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                                "ArchivoNarrow-Regular.ttf");       
                        ((TextView) arg0.getChildAt(0)).setTypeface(myTypeface);
                        int a = sitesSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        switch (a) {
                        case (0):

                                    review = LoginActivity.reviews;                                             
                                    for (int i = 0; i < review.length(); i++) {
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject c = review
                                                    .getJSONObject(i);
                                            int review_profile_id2 = Integer.parseInt(c
                                                    .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEWS_PRIOFILE_ID));
                                            if (review_profile_id == review_profile_id2){
                                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                                String url = c
                                                        .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_URL);
                                                String author = c
                                                        .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_AUTHOR);
                                                String author1 =  Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
                                                String date = c
                                                        .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_DATE);
                                                String review1 = c
                                                        .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEW);
                                                String review =  Html.fromHtml(review1).toString();
                                                String rating = c
                                                        .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_RATING);
                                                String link_raw  = c.getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REDIRECT);
                                                String link =  Html.fromHtml(link_raw).toString();

                                                if (!review
                                                        .equals("null")) {
                                                    if (url.equals(dealer)) {
                                                        map.put("review",
                                                                review);
                                                        map.put("author", author);
                                                        map.put("date",
                                                                date);
                                                        map.put("service", link);
                                                        map.put("rating",
                                                                rating);
                                                        map.put("url", Integer.toString(dealer_image));

                                                        listItems
                                                                .add(map);
                                                    } else if (url
                                                            .equals(google)) {
                                                        map.put("review",
                                                                review);
                                                        map.put("author", author);
                                                        map.put("date",
                                                                date);
                                                        map.put("rating",
                                                                rating);
                                                        map.put("service", link);
                                                        map.put("url", Integer.toString(google_image));

                                                        listItems
                                                                .add(map);
                                                    } 

                                                }
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // Getting adapter
                                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                            DashboardActivity.this,
                                            listItems,
                                            R.layout.list_item, str,
                                            place);
                                    ((SimpleAdapter) adapter)
                                            .setViewBinder(new MyBinder());
                                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                                    break;
                        case (1):
                            review = LoginActivity.reviews;                                 
                        for (int i = 0; i < review.length(); i++) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject c = review
                                        .getJSONObject(i);
                                String url = c
                                        .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_URL);
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                int review_profile_id2 = Integer.parseInt(c
                                        .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEWS_PRIOFILE_ID));
                                if (review_profile_id == review_profile_id2) {
                                    if (url.equals(dealer)) {
                                        String review1 = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REVIEW);
                                        String review =  Html.fromHtml(review1).toString();
                                        String author = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_AUTHOR);
                                        String date = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_DATE);
                                        String rating = c
                                                .getString(LoginActivity.TAG_RATING);
                                        String link_raw  = c.getString(LoginActivity.TAG_REDIRECT);
                                        String link =  Html.fromHtml(link_raw).toString();

                                        if (!review
                                                .equals("null")) {
                                            map.put("review",
                                                    review);
                                            map.put("author", author);
                                            map.put("date",
                                                    date);
                                            map.put("rating",
                                                    rating);
                                            map.put("service", link);
                                            map.put("url", Integer.toString(dealer_image));


                                            listItems
                                                    .add(map);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        // Getting adapter
                        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                DashboardActivity.this,
                                listItems,
                                R.layout.list_item, str,
                                place);
                        ((SimpleAdapter) adapter)
                                .setViewBinder(new MyBinder());
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                        break;              
                        }
                    }
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                }
            });




        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(login);
                // Closing dashboard screen
                finish();
            }
        });

    } else {
        // user is not logged in show login screen
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                LoginActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }
}

class MyBinder implements ViewBinder {      
    public boolean setViewValue(final View view, final Object data,
            String textRepresentation) {        
        if (view.getId() == R.id.rating) {
            String stringval = (String) data;
            float ratingValue = Float.parseFloat(stringval);
            RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) view;
            ratingBar.setRating(ratingValue);
            return true;
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.date) {            
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            String stringval = (String) data;
            Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                    "ArchivoNarrow-Regular.ttf");       
            textView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            textView.setText(stringval);
            return true;
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.author) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            String stringval = (String) data;
            Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                    "ArchivoNarrow-Regular.ttf");       
            textView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            textView.setText(stringval);
            return true;
        }

        if (view.getId() == R.id.urlImage) {
            ImageButton image = (ImageButton) view;
            String stringval = (String) data;   
            final int imageSource = Integer.parseInt(stringval);
            image.setBackgroundResource(imageSource);
            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    if(imageSource == dealer_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == google_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == cars_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == edmunds_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == yelp_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == yahoo_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == judi_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == insider_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == city_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == facebook_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(imageSource == twitter_image){
                        TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                        String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(shareFact);
                        Log.d("ImageButton", shareFact);
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.review) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            String stringval = (String) data;
            Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                    "ArchivoNarrow-Regular.ttf");       
            textView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            textView.setText(stringval);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

line no 127 is:

```
for (int i = -1; i < profile.length()+1; i++)
```

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: post your  DashboardActivity class and mention line the code line no 127

Comment: i have posted my DashboardActivity class and line no 127. @rajeshwaran

Comment: profile = LoginActivity.profiles;  In this line, profile value is null. thats why you got null pointer exception. so please check LoginActivity.profile in loginactivity.

Comment: now i am setting the value of profile globally. when user will log in by giving their details, all the profile values is storing globally in this application. and 1st time it is running successfully but the prob arise when i am restarting the device. Can you tell me why? @rajeshwaran